# How to count average word per sentence in python and saving by each article in a list?

Tags: python, text, nlp

I am having a problem counting average words per sentence from dataframe. Here that's what I want to do

```
"On Saturday, September 17 at 8:30 pm EST, an explosion rocked West 23 Street in Manhattan, in the neighborhood commonly referred to as Chelsea, injuring 29 people, smashing windows and initiating street closures. There were no fatalities. Officials maintain that a homemade bomb, which had been placed in a dumpster, created the explosion.
```

```
2+6+8+8+3+6/6 = 5.6 for first sentence
4/1 = 4 for second sentence
6+7+3/3=5.1 for the third sentence
```

After that, I want to save the average word per sentence in each article within list.

I am really appreciate anyone help thank you!

Comment: How do you define a sentence? I'm sure my definition is different than yours. :-)

Comment: How do you define a word? I'm sure my definition is different than yours. :)

Comment: @erip a sentence defines by looking at full stop :")

Comment: @OliverMason the date, number, time also word

Comment: The second sentence has 4 words of length 5, 4, 2, 10. So `4/4 = 1 for the second sentence` seems to be wrong. Are you sure your results are correct ?

Comment: @RishiDev the second sentence is "there were no fatalities". there are 4 words divided into 1 as there are no separation like commas, !, or ?. So it should be 4/1 = 4 so sorry :/ I will edit my calculation

Comment: @RosyIndahPermatasari, I have corrected the answer, hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First you get a list of lines separated by `.`

Then you get the phrases separated by `,`

Then you get the words in each phrase separated by `space`

Then you get the sum of lengths of each word and divide by total number of words

```py
text = "On Saturday, September 17 at 8:30 pm EST, an explosion rocked West 23 Street in Manhattan, in the neighborhood commonly referred to as Chelsea, injuring 29 people, smashing windows and initiating street closures. There were no fatalities. Officials maintain that a homemade bomb, which had been placed in a dumpster, created the explosion."

lines = text.strip('.').split('.')
print("There are", len(lines), "lines present")

for line in lines:
    phrases = line.split(',')
    phrases = [phrase.strip() for phrase in phrases]
    words = [phrase.split() for phrase in phrases]
    lengths = [len(word) for word in words]
    print(f"{sum(lengths)}/{len(lengths)}={sum(lengths)/len(lengths)}")
```

Output:

```sh
There are 3 lines present
33/6=5.5
4/1=4.0
16/3=5.333333333333333
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue ?

Comment: It doesn't yield the results that OP posted (because it doesn't capture numbers)